Can't boot Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W
I have a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W and I'm trying to run Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server on it. I flashed the microSD card using the Raspberry Pi Imager, put the card in the slot and powered it up. The green LED came on for a second or so and then shut off. So:

The only 24.04 image listed in the imager is a 64-bit one. Is there a 32-bit image for 24.04?

Has anyone gotten the 24.04 image to work on a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W? It only has 512 MB of RAM but it has four cores.



Thanks! I'll tell the Raspberry Pi imager folks they need to remove it from their menu.

Sure! I was looking for a button to flag it as a solution and didn't see one.

Not Enough RAM
According to Ubuntu 24.04 server official site, it needs at least 1024 MB RAM.
Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W has only MB RAM.
Try Ubuntu Core
You may try Ubuntu Core 24, with minimum RAM requirement of 512 MB. Ubuntu Core is a lighter version of Ubuntu designed of IoT hardware like Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W. See more on Ubuntu Core at the official documentation.
The installation of Ubuntu Core is slightly different from installing the Ubuntu server ISO. See instructions here
64 bit OS may not be the problem
Ubuntu does not have any 32 bit versions for their current offerings. However, according to the Raspberry Pi OS page

the 64 bit PiOS should work on Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W.
Hope this helps
